# "to the right" vs. "at the right"

Tags: prepositions

I'm confused about the use of "**at**" or "**to**" in the following sentence:

> This function puts the number at/to right of the equal into a new set

I see a lot of people using "at" but I am pretty sure that it's wrong! Which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*At* is used when the position is absolute; *to* is used when the position is relative.

Since, the context is about a position with respect to 'equal' thing, *to* is used predominantly.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about American English, but in British English I would expect "to" and not "at".  For example, you might see: -

> This function puts the number to the right of the equal into a new set
>
> This function puts the number on the right-hand-side into a new set
>
> This function puts the number on the right into a new set
>
> This function puts the right-hand number into a new set

So, quite a few options, but none of them use "at".  In truth, I think you are more likely to encounter "on" than "to", and "to" is more likely than "at".

Comment: I would expect "to" in American English, as well.

Comment: nice answer which is related to common usage.